# Change font color to Red when text has "*" in a cell - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In a cell I have a value e.g: "World is not fair *"

- In this text I want to change font color only to Red for `*`
- The`*`will be my last letter

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to buy a can of red paint and small brush and very carefully paint it

Answer (score 2):

This code will colour the last character of a cell red:

```
Range("A1").Characters(Len(Range("A1"))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Len() gives the number of characters, then Characters() refers to this last character.

Answer (score 1):

For a range of cells you could try something like this

```
Sub UpdateRange()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = [a1:a10]
For Each rng2 In rng1
If Len(rng2.Value) > 0 Then
    If Right$(rng2.Value, 1) = "*" Then rng2.Characters(Len(rng2.Value)).Font.Color = vbRed
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting to do this.

You need to select the option "use a formula to determine which cells to format".

Then you type in this formula -depending on which cell it is.

=RIGHT(A1,1)="*"

You then click on format and choose font and select colour red.

Comment: I think that colors the entire word red as opposed to just the `*`?

Comment: Sorry must have misread it.  That one stumps me.